# np completeness

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reduction Algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3358/reduction-algorithms)

Hi,

I am thinking of researching in this area and am doing some analysis now. Need your help understanding the NP Completeness. I went through the article on monotone one-in-three 3SAT in wikipedia and I see that is NP Complete. We generally use 3 SAT for satisfiability problems. My question is if I am given a boolean SAT with variations from normal satisfiable problem like say no literals negated. i.e I have input in the form (x v y v z) ^ (x v y v z) no negations. Then proving it belongs to NP is easy. We just assign value 1 to all literals X,Y and Z. If output is 1 it is SAT else not . Now can I use this boolean SAT , to prove decision problems like say : if I am interested in setting only minimum values to 1 to check for SAT. My problem will be what is the minimum values that are to be set to 1 to check if the input clause is satisfiable? How can I prove this for NP Completeness

Also

For the NP Completeness I see examples of problems like vertex cover, Hamiltonian graphs etc. Can we use this to the real time combinatorial algorithms, like problem of bidding for items. say I have some x items to be sold and only y bids left. Then I can choose any combination for each auction. And with constraints like ensuring an item is sold only once, only sell if max price is reached and so on...? How do we prove NP Completeness for such problems.

Comment: Start by Googling for: computational complexity game theory.

Comment: Duplicate. Vote to close.